# Homepage not being crawled by search engines

Tags: wordpress, web-crawlers, robots.txt

*My website is using WordPress with the following robots.txt*

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin
Disallow: /wp-admin
Disallow: /wp-includes    
Disallow: /wp-content/cache
Disallow: /trackback
Disallow: /*trackback
Disallow: /*trackback*
Disallow: /*/trackback
Disallow: /*?*
Disallow: /*.html/$
Disallow: /*feed*

# Google Image
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:
Allow: /*

# Google AdSense
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
Disallow:
Allow: /*
```

I updated the `robots.txt` file 3 days ago and the problem I'm having is when I search for the site on Google or Bing it shows all sub pages but not the home page. Google says the following for the homepage:

> A description for this result is not available because of this site's
>   robots.txt – learn more.

I tested using Google webmaster tools and it shows no errors. 
It shows description of home page when is search with `site:domainname.com`.
Is this a WordPress issue or does my robots.txt file have errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have also faced similar issue on our website. This happened because initially you must have disallowed your home page in robots.txt.
Now even if you allow, it takes sometime **around a week-two to reflect in google indexes**.

I have tested your robots.txt and it looks fine.